# Incorrect Signature in facebook stream_publish call

Tags: magento, facebook

I am having a facebook error on stream_publish call. I actually used an extension for Magento for Fconnect. Fconnect & Flogin is working fine. But it is requirement that when user place an order it should be posted on user's wall. For that I have implemented like this

```
document.observe('click', function(e){

    if (e.element().match('a[rel^=facebook-connect]') || e.element().match('button[rel^=facebook-connect]')) {

        e.stop();

        FB.login(function(response){



            if(response.status=='connected') setLocation('http://staging.mystore.com/facebook/customer_account/connect/');



        }, {perms:"email,publish_stream"});

    }

});
```

in Facebook Client file generateSignature method is like this

```
private function _generateSig($params_array)
{
    Mage::log($params_array);
    $str = '';
    ksort($params_array);
    foreach ($params_array as $k=>$v) {
        $str .= "$k=$v";
    }

    $str .= $this->_secret;
    Mage::log($str);
    Mage::log('md5 sigs:: ' . md5($str));

    return md5($str);
}
```

& My code that is calling the API is like this

```
    $message = 'just placed an order on mystore.com';

     $attachment = array(
     'name' => "mystore",
     'href' => 'http://www.mystore.com/',
     'description' => 'New order on mystore.com',
     'media' => array(array('type' => 'image',
     'src' => 'http://www.mystore.com/skin/frontend/default/mystore/images/logo.png',
     'href' => 'http://www.mystore.com/')));

     $action_links = array( array('text' => 'Buy@mystore', 'href' => 'http://www.mystore.com/'));

     $attachment = json_encode($attachment);
     $action_links = json_encode($action_links);

     try{
         // if( $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $action_links, null, $target_id))
         if($this->_getClient()->call( 'facebook.stream.publish', 
                                array($message, $attachment, $action_links, 
                                        $this->_getClient()->users->getLoggedInUser(), 
                                        Mage::getSingleton('facebook/config')->getApiKey() )
                                 )  ) 
         {
            Mage::log( "Added on FB Wall" );
         }

        } catch(Exception $e) 
        {
            Mage::log( "Exception in wall write" );

            Mage::log($e);
        }
```

After logging the Signature I found in log is

```
api_key=XXXXXXXXmethod=facebook.stream.publishsession_key=2.AQCm5fABfobInAS5.3600.1309352400.1-1000025660978090=just placed an order on mystore.comcall_id=1309345883.3068format=JSONv=1.01={"name":"mystore","href":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/","description":"New order on mystore.com","media":[{"type":"image","src":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/mystore\/images\/logo.png","href":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/"}]}2=[{"text":"Buy@mystore","href":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/"}]3=1000025660978094=5070afefb42b162aff748f55ecf44d110d9e2a90117ee1704e2adb41f1d190fa
```

I have never done any development on Facebook SO I have no Idea what to do? Please help me with solution. & let me know if u guys need any other info to understand this.

Oh yeah One more thing the Client File code that is calling Api (call method) its like this

```
private function _prepareParams($method, $params)
{

    $defaultParams = array(
        'api_key' => $this->_apiKey,
        'call_id' => microtime(true),
        'format'  => 'JSON',
        'v'       => '1.0'
    );

    if($this->_sessionKey){
        $defaultParams['session_key'] = $this->_sessionKey;
    }

    $params = array_merge($defaultParams, $params);
    foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
        if (!is_array($val)) continue;
        $val = Zend_Json::encode($val);
    }

    $params['method'] = $method;

    if(isset($params['sig'])) {
        unset($params['sig']);
    }
    $params['sig'] = $this->_generateSig($params);

    return $params;
}


public function call($method, $args=array())
{
    Mage::log($args);
    $params = $this->_prepareParams($method, $args);

    $client = self::_getHttpClient()
            ->setUri(self::FACEBOOK_REST_URI)
            ->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST)
            ->resetParameters()
            ->setParameterPost($params);    

    try {
        $response = $client->request();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Service unavaliable');
    }

    if(!$response->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Service unavaliable');
    }

    $result = Zend_Json::decode($response->getBody());

    //json decode returns float on long uid number? is_json check? old php?
    if(is_float($result)){
        $result = $response->getBody();
    }

    if(is_array($result) && isset($result['error_code'])) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception($result['error_msg'], $result['error_code']);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

For calling API I used two ways `$this->_getClient()->call( 'facebook.stream.publish',`
& `$this->_getClient()->call( 'stream_publish',` 
None of them are working

Answer (score 0):

ok GUys I figure out the mistake

look at my code

```
format=JSONv=1.01={"name":"mystore","href":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/","description":"New order on mystore.com","media":[{"type":"image","src":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/mystore\/images\/logo.png","href":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/"}]}2=[{"text":"Buy@mystore","href":"http:\/\/www.mystore.com\/"}]3=1000025660978094=5070afefb42b162aff748f55ecf44d110d9e2a90117ee1704e2adb41f1d190fa
```

where u can see **format=JSONv=1.01={....}2=[{.....}]** the problem was I used numeric arrays for parameters. they should be associated arrays
like **message={new order}attachment={....}** 
Once I fixed the associative array problem my code start working correctly 
here is a link that'll give u detail about parameters to pass to stream.publish
http://schoolout.net/en/developers/view/39

Hope this will help somebody else too.